# Python script that runs in commandline detects keypress everywhere

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, keypress

currently im Working on a small project for myself and im detecting keypresses in my script but it also detects them while im typing for example in a game

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
    sys.exit()
```

how can I prevent it from doing it and only detect when i have the cmd open

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Keyboard library is to hook global key presses, i.e., out of focus as they said in their [docs](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard).

> Don't do this! The `keyboard` module is meant for global events,
> even when your program is not in focus.

To get the keys when the window is focused, you can try the below solutions.

**Solution 1:**

You can use **[getkey](https://github.com/kcsaff/getkey)** library. You have to install it with pip.

```
pip install getkey
```

And implement it like this:

```
from getkey import getkey
while True:
    key = getkey()
    print(key)
    if key == "q":
        break
```

**Solution 2:**

If you are a **Windows** user, you can use getch() in **msvcrt** module like this:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key = msvcrt.getch()
        print("Key Pressed", key)
        if key == "q":
            break
```